# Solution to a static indexed value

Tags: c++, singleton, operator-overloading

Please see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum dataType {
    DATATYPE_BYTE,
    DATATYPE_CHAR, 
    DATATYPE_UCHAR,
    DATATYPE_SHORT,
    DATATYPE_USHORT,
    DATATYPE_INT,
    DATATYPE_UINT,
    DATATYPE_LONG,
    DATATYPE_ULONG,
    DATATYPE_FLOAT,
    DATATYPE_UFLOAT,
    DATATYPE_DOUBLE,
    DATATYPE_UDOUBLE,

    DATATYPE_BLOB,
    DATATYPE_STRING,
    DATATYPE_COMPLEX, 

    DATATYPE_MORE, 
    DATATYPE_ERROR
};

typedef struct typenamepair_ {
    const dataType name;
    const char* const nameval ;
} typenamepair;

class types {
    private:
        typenamepair *typesArr;
        static typenamepair TYPES[];
        static types* instance_;
    public:
        static types* getInstance() {
            if ( !instance_ )
                instance_ = new types;

            return instance_;
        }
        const char* operator[](dataType typeEnum)
        {
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < (sizeof(types::TYPES)/sizeof(typenamepair)); ++i ) {
                if ( i == TYPES[i].name  )
                    return TYPES[i].nameval;
            }
            // failed to get value. return error
            return TYPES[DATATYPE_ERROR].nameval;
        }
};

types* types::instance_ = NULL;
typenamepair types::TYPES[] = {
    { DATATYPE_BYTE, "byte" },
    { DATATYPE_CHAR, "char" },
    { DATATYPE_UCHAR, "u_char" },
    { DATATYPE_SHORT, "short" },
    { DATATYPE_USHORT, "u_short" },
    { DATATYPE_INT, "int" },
    { DATATYPE_UINT, "u_int" },
    { DATATYPE_FLOAT, "float"},
    { DATATYPE_UFLOAT, "u_float"},
    { DATATYPE_DOUBLE, "double"},
    { DATATYPE_UDOUBLE, "u_double"},
    { DATATYPE_STRING, "cstring"},
    { DATATYPE_BLOB, "blob"},
    { DATATYPE_COMPLEX, "complex"},
    { DATATYPE_MORE, "more"},

    // Unknown type!
    { DATATYPE_ERROR, "ERROR"}
};


main()
{
    const char* test = (types::getInstance())[DATATYPE_UINT] ;
    cout << test << endl;
}
```

Gives me the following compilation errors:

test.cpp: In member function 'const char* types::operator':
test.cpp:53: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'typenamepair []' 
test.cpp: In function 'int main()':
test.cpp:87: error: cannot convert 'types' to 'const char*' in initialization

What is wrong with size of and how can I fix it?
Also, how can I use the returned instace to use the operator to get the typename?

Also, please let me know if there is a better solution.
Thanks

Comment: 1. singleton is irrelevant to your problem. simplifying your example would help us help you
 2. you can use `dataType` as an index of your array so you won't need to iterate it

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot use the datatype as index as it needs to be defined in accordance with API specs. Will make sure to remove non-relevant code next time. Thanks. What is the alternative if not singleton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first error, you need to move the code using `sizeof` until after the array contents have been defined.  There is [a better way to get the array size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124534/computing-length-of-array/1124556#1124556) but it also can't be used until the contents are defined.

For your second error, you have a pointer, so your user-defined `operator[]` isn't being found.  Change `getInstance` to return a reference instead of a pointer and it should work.

Comment: Can you pls explain how to use .nameval?

Comment: @Kiran: Sorry, I didn't see that you were trying to redefine `operator[]`.  The problem is that your user defined `operator[]` exists for `types` and not `types*`... `operator[]` on a pointer always means array access and cannot be redefined.  Replace the pointer with a reference and everything should be ok.

Comment: If you dont mind, can you explain me the significance of (&) in this solution?

`template <typename T, std::size_t N>
std::size_t size(T (&)[N])
{
    return N;
}`

Comment: @Kiran, it means a reference.  `T&` would be a reference to a single `T` object, and `T (&)[N]` is a reference to an array of N `T` objects.