# How to get size of an array using metaprogramming?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Use templates to get an array's size and end address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073276/use-templates-to-get-an-arrays-size-and-end-address)
>
> [Can someone explain this template code that gives me the size of an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array) (the first answer includes obtaining the value as a compile time constant)

How to get size of an array using metaprogramming? Multidimensional would be also appreciated.
So for example if I pass a type to this struct (how ever it's called, let's say get_dim) I would get:

```
get_dim<int>::value; //0
get_dim<int[1]>::value //1
get_dim<int[2][3]>::value //2,3
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Could you add a better description of the problem and constraints?  Or maybe an example of what a solution might look like, if you had a partial idea in mind?

Comment: Make a little effort and **search for duplicates**. *[c++] array size* in the search box will provide multiple solutions. I could just paste the solution here and get some rep. but please just **make the slightest effort**, you have been around the site long enough to try and searching by yourself.

Comment: @David so you're here to answer questions or to show people that they cannot search etc etc?

Comment: @There:  The FAQ says right at the top: "Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. "  Why would you think you are exempt from this?

Comment: @There is nothing we can do: I provided the search criteria in the comment so that you can consider doing something similar in the future in case you did not know that you could search or that you could use tags in the search. Of course, as you said some time ago, it is much easier not to bother and just ask and get others to do the work for you...

Comment: @David - before lecturing people about not using your search terms, why not test to make sure the items that show up in that search are relevant to the question asked? : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]+array+size <- I don't see a single one.

Comment: The question duplicate is very similar, but the answer over there doesn't apply.

Comment: I find google/bing search is better at finding results than the stackoverflow search. Just tack `site:stackoverflow.com` on the end of your search queries and BAM! Answers!

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: I don't know whether the results are not deterministic, but the third result is [In regards to array size calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033497/in-regards-to-array-size-calculation) that is a templated version, that also links to other duplicate answers, the first of which has a very extensive [answer by litb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437150/can-someone-explain-this-template-code-that-gives-me-the-size-of-an-array/437178#437178) including how to obtain a compile time constant with that value. There it is, completely chewed up and easy to digest.

Comment: @david - neither of those answer the question posted here.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: The question posted here or the last edit after the comment, and the vote to close?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one dimensional Arrays,

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t size_of_array(T (&)[N])
{
   return N;
}

int arr[]={1,2,2,3,4,4,4,54,5};
cout << size_of_array(arr) << endl;     

A a[] = {A(),A(), A(), A(), A()};
cout << size_of_array(a) << endl;
```

Output:

```
9
5
```

Full Demo at Ideone : http://ideone.com/tpWk8

---

EDIT:

Another way (after seeing your edit),

```
template<typename T>
struct get_dim;

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct get_dim<T[N]>
{
    static const int value = N;
};

int main() 
{
       cout << get_dim<int[100]>::value;
       return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
100
```

http://ideone.com/wdFuz

---

EDIT:

For two dimensional arrays:

```
struct size2D
{
   size_t X;
   size_t Y;
};

template<typename T, size_t M, size_t N>
size2D size_of_array(T (&)[M][N])
{
   size2D s = { M, N};
   return s;
}
int arr[][5]={ {1,2,2,5,3}, {4,4,4,54,5}} ;
size2D size = size_of_array(arr);
cout << size.X <<", "<< size.Y << endl;
```

Output:

```
2, 5
```

Code : http://ideone.com/2lrUq

Comment: Better to use enums instead of static integers.  Enums are always constant expressions.

Comment: @Crazy: Where should I use enum? And is that the reason of downvote?

Comment: You should use enum in place of static integers in your metafunctions.  The negative is for posting an answer to a question that you also closed.

Comment: @Crazy: What is wrong with static int? Also, why can't I reply a question, and then close it after finding a duplicate?

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is present in [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html), specifically, `boost::rank<>` and `boost::extent<>`.

If you want to know *how* it's done, see other answers, or the Boost source code.